# How do I disable paging of help in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

By default, when you use `help` in PowerShell, the output is paged using `more`. If you install PSCX, it gives you the option of using `less` instead. By default, I'd rather use neither (I have a sufficiently large scrollback buffer on my console window). `Get-Help` doesn't page the output

How do I turn off paging of `help` in PowerShell? Without having to type more?

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe. `Get-Help` on my (Windows 7 x86) system does not page the output. Running `Get-Help` alone gives me `"Get-help" and "-?" display help on one page. "Help" displayes help on multiple pages.`

Comment: You're right; I want to turn off paging for `help`. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alias `help` to `get-help`:

> `new-alias help get-help`

Answer (score 0):

The function `help` wraps the `Get-Help` command, sets some defaults, and formats the output.

Dump the contents of the function like this:

```
PS> (get-command help).definition
```

Of particular note, at least in my installation, it turns on the `-Full` parameter by default, and it pipes the output to the command specified in the `PAGER` environment variable if set, or otherwise using `more`.

So if you want to get the full output but skip the pager stuff, just call `Get-Help` directly with the `-Full` parameter set:

```
PS> get-help -full some-command
```